# How can I modify the basic XNA draw method to do vertex (point) rendering?

Tags: c#, xna, rendering

I have been following the MSDN documentation on how to [render a model with a basic effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203933.aspx).

Which is neat. I can change the rendering to display in wireframe by adding the following line to the example code, before the DrawModel method's double loop:

`GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = WIREFRAME_RASTERIZER_STATE;`

Where I've initialized WIREFRAME_RASTERIZER_STATE in the constructor as

`RasterizerState WIREFRAME_RASTERIZER_STATE = new RasterizerState() { CullMode = CullMode.None, FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame };`

Is there an equally easy addition/modification I can make to display *just* the vertices in the imported model? From my understanding, Wireframe mode tells XNA to render lines instead of triangles, but unfortunately the RasterizerState method that I used above doesn't have a fill mode that displays just the vertices (it's SOLID or WIREFRAME).

Given that most of the `draw` functionality is hidden in the MSDN example, I was hoping someone could direct me as to how to simply render the points without connecting them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FillMode.Point` was removed in XNA 4.0. [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/03/22/point-sprites-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx) describes why, and provides work-arounds.

In your situation you will probably find that you have to process the model data to generate actual triangles to render in place of points.